# How to add ak set of keys + values in dictionaries inside a list inside a dictionary

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I'm learning to use ReactJs but I don't understand how I could add a key + value to a set of dictionaries contained in a list itself contained in a dictionary ...?

here are the datas :

```
export const datasTest = {
  labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "# of Red Votes",
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
    },
    {
      label: "# of Blue Votes",
      data: [2, 3, 20, 5, 1, 4],
    },
    {
      label: "# of Green Votes",
      data: [3, 10, 13, 15, 22, 30],
    },
  ],
};
```

So i would like to get this :

```
export const datasTest = {
  labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "# of Red Votes",
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: "#c4b02e",
    },
    {
      label: "# of Blue Votes",
      data: [2, 3, 20, 5, 1, 4],
      backgroundColor: "#f3bf1d",
    },
    {
      label: "# of Green Votes",
      data: [3, 10, 13, 15, 22, 30],
      backgroundColor: "#fb601f",
    },
  ],
};
```

I added '**backgroundColor: "#fb601f"**' (by hand :))

with

```
export const colorForLabel = [
  { label: "# of Red Votes", colour: "#c4b02e" },
  { label: "# of Blue Votes", colour: "#f3bf1d" },
  { label: "# of Green Votes", colour: "#fb601f" },
];
```

I writted this, but i'm stuck, i don't know how to append my new values :

```
  const [data, setDatas] = useState(
    CscDataService.getDatas()
  );

  function setColor() {
    {
      Object.entries(data["datasets"]).map(([key, values]) => {
        Object.entries(values).map(([key, value]) => {
          console.log(key + " " + value);
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Can you give me a hand ? Thanks

Comment: Okay, but how do you choose the backgroundColor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```js
function setColor() {
  const updatedDatasets = data.datasets.map(dataset => {
    const { colour } = colorForLabel.find(({ label }) => label === dataset.label) || {};
    
    return {
      ...dataset,
      backgroundColor:colour 
    }
  });
  
  setDatas(currentData => ({
    ...curentData,
    datasets: updatedDatasets
  }));
}
};
```

Comment: Yes, i tried it and its ok [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-flower-bh5hq?file=/src/App.js) thank you. I prefer your solution which is more readable for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functional state update to get access to the previous state and add backgroundColor to each object like:

```
export const colorForLabel = [
  { label: "# of Red Votes", colour: "#c4b02e" },
  { label: "# of Blue Votes", colour: "#f3bf1d" },
  { label: "# of Green Votes", colour: "#fb601f" },
];

function setColor() {
    setDatas((prevData) => {
        return {
            ...prevData,
            datasets: prevData.datasets.map(dataset => ({...dataset, backgroundColor: colorForLabel.find(({label}) => label === dataset.label).colour}))
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Great, it works for me : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-gareth-sr13t?file=/src/App.js). Thanks